# How can I check if an element from one observable exists in another in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have two list elements side by side.

```
NEW      |     APPROVED
-------------------------
ONE   [X]      ONE
TWO   [ ]      THREE
THREE [X]
```

I have a checkbox that when clicked will disable the checkbox so I can't click it again, and add a class to the parent list element. That element then shows on the "APPROVED" list.

All of this is working great as a user is actually using the application.

When the page loads, the list(s) are populated correctly, but I'm not sure how to apply the class/disable the checkbox to the elements in the "NEW" list.

When a user clicks the checkbox, I am simply setting a variable in my `.ts` file:

```
constructor() {
    isApproved: boolean = false;
    ...
}

...

// item has been clicked and status updated into db.
item.isApproved = true;

...
do other stuff
```

Here is what my html looks like:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" [ngClass]="{approved: item.isApproved}">
    ...
</ion-item>
```

In my constructor, I am not sure how to check what items are in the "APPROVED" list when the page loads and then apply a class to my "NEW" list. I know that Items in the "APPROVED" list are showing correctly, those are the items that need to have the class applied to them in the "NEW" column.

In really, *really* simple js it would be something like:

```
foreach(item In New list as item) {
   if (item is in approved list) {
        item.isApproved = true;
   }
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

write the following code snippet in the constructor or ngOnInit method to set the isApproved field:

```
NewList.forEach(item=>{
    approvedList.forEach(approvedItem=>{
        if(item.text===approvedItem.text){
            item.isApproved = true;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Praveen - I believe what you have is exactly what I need to try. This is what is generating my "Approved" list: `.map(res => {return res;})` So you are suggesting that I can run the `forEach` on my `res` object?

Comment: @Damon, yes. You have to apply the for each on res object.